# Getting Context in onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

In my android app: How can I get access to Context in the onCreate method of the SQLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` and in your own constructor, save it to a field. Then, later, in `onCreate()` you have access to the context.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I get a NPE when trying to access the member field during `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend that class and pass the context to the constructor, which stores it inside a variable. You then can access it from within the onCreate method.